# Can responsiveslides.js be used in the page background?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using reponsiveslides.js to create a slideshow that fills the browser background 100% in width and height.

However, I'd like to use it in the background---behind the page content. When I have tried to place content in the container div, it seems to show up behind the sideshow; when I place it outside of the slides container div, I can seem to pull it up and on top of it.

I am sure this is a quick fix if someone can give me some pointers.

Here's some code:

```
<div id="container">

<ul class="rslides">
 <li><img src="img/highway.jpg" alt=""></li>
 <li><img src="img/sunset.jpg" alt=""></li>
 <li><img src="img/rocksLeaves.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function () {

  // Slideshow 1
  $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    speed: 2000,
  });

});
```

```
<div id="content">
<p>put stuff here</p>
</div>


</div>
```

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4GPX/5/)

Comment: Could make the z-index of the slideshow 1 and then give the div containing all of the content you want above it a z-index of 2 or 3? (using CSS..)

Comment: Your images aren't visible, use complete links in the fiddle

Comment: I have updated the image links to ones on a server...thank you

Comment: Edited again because I had container in markup and window in css

Comment: @JordanPlahn suggestion did work...in that the content is now on top of the slideshow. But with an absolute position and top:0, how do I get the content to center in the browser window?

Comment: Try "margin:0 auto;" on the content.

Comment: I've got that; it still sticks to the left; I can use percentages (left:50%) etc...but then it doesn't center when you resize the window.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/jplahn/8QBjM/1/ Notice how it always centers. Did you apply that to containing div instead of the content?

Comment: I will try this...thank you. I know it is some combination of this stuff that is tripping me up.

Comment: Let me know if you get it! Good luck.

Comment: @JordanPlahn, if I don't put position absolute and top:0, the content disappears; but I can't center the content in the window if it is set to position absolute; even with you suggestion about having a containing div with a width and then content inside it with margin 0 auto....